# Toast if EditTest is Empty

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pop a message that the `EditText` is empty. I can't make it work. I guess it's trying to convert an `Integer` to a `String`.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);


public void buttonPressed (View view){
    System.out.println(randomNumber);

    EditText numberField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textField);
    String numberString = numberField.getText().toString();
    int numberText = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
    String message = "";

    if (randomNumber == numberText){
        message = "Correct Number";

    }
    else if (randomNumber > numberText){
        message = "Number too Low";

    }
    else if (randomNumber < numberText){
        message = "Number too High";
    }
    else if(numberString.matches("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: *I can't make it work* => any error message ? I would guess the same as you based on the above, you probably have a `NumberFormatException` that crashes your app...

Comment: It is probably best that you remove `I'm new with Android Programming. Please help me with my code.`  from your question and insert the error message you are getting instead.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer ! See my edit about limiting the user input to numbers. Please do take the time to go through the accepted answer for the question I link to as well, it will teach you how to effectively debug the app on your own, thus gaining productivity and experience at the same time. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App crashes :

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

If the crash is a `NumberFormatException` :

encapsulate your call to `parseInt` in a `try/catch` block and check if the `EditText` is empty first :

```
if (numberString.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    try {
        int numberText = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        // the rest of your code
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e(getClass.getSimpleName(), e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

**EDIT** : to ensure the user can only insert a number, you can use the `inputType` property of `EditText` :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
    style="@style/yourStyle"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse an integer even if the field is empty which will throw a `NumberFormatException`. You will need to handle the case where the user does not enter a valid number. To get started though try the following:

```
public void buttonPressed (View view) {
    System.out.println(randomNumber);

    EditText numberField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textField);
    String numberString = numberField.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(numberString)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // FIXME: add code to handle invalid integer here
        int numberText = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        String message = "";

        if (randomNumber == numberText){
            message = "Correct Number";
        }
        else if (randomNumber > numberText){
            message = "Number too Low";
        }
        else if (randomNumber < numberText){
            message = "Number too High";
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(numberString.equals(""))
   {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would put that as the first thing, because if you have an empty value, then you will get a `NumberFormatException` when converting, and as a result, it will crash. Move your check for that to before the `parseInt` command.

```
String numberString = numberField.getText().toString();
if(numberString.matches("")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
int numberText = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
```

Even better would be to put the parseInt inside of a try/catch, and then do the number checks.

```
try {
    int numberText = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
    // Put checks in here to see if the number is right
} catch (NumberException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid entry detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer (Click on the box that looks like a check), or upvote it when you get the reputation to do so.